# Python Pandas - get an average of 'SNOW' per month from each location/ 'NAME'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, group-by, datasource

I have a .csv file named Data.csv. I need to find the average of snow per month at each location or 'NAME'. Then I need to save each years totals, 2016 and 2017 to separate .csv files. I'm using pandas. Not sure where to start.

This is what I have right now from things I've put together through researching.

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

gname = df2.groupby('NAME')

for NAME, Name_df2 in data:
    df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'])
    df2.groupby([df.DATE.dt.month,'NAME','SNOW']).mean().sort_values()
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there an error message? How about giving us some sample data?

Comment: few things wrong with this to start. I'd give us an example dataframe to work with since we can't access Data.csv, so create something like `pd.DataFrame({'NAME':['Boston','Boston','New York', 'New York'], 'year':[2016, 2017, 2017, 2016], 'totals':[5.6, 66, 87, 55]})` or something like that. The other thing is that I'm not seeing where you define data anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Need you to provide us with example data first. but this is somewhere directional:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
g = df.groupby([df.DATE.dt.year, df.DATE.dt.month, 'NAME'])['SNOW'].mean().reset_index().sort_values()

df_2016 = df.loc[df.DATE.dt.year == 2016]
df_2016.to_csv('2016 snow totals.csv', index=False)
df_2017 = df.loc[df.DATE.dt.year == 2017]
df_2017.to_csv('2017 snow totals.csv', index=False)
```

if you have more than just 2 years, you should split the grouped dataframe into a list and iterate through it like..

```
for year in range(df.DATE.dt.year.min(), df.DATE.dt.year.max()):
    df.loc[df.DATE.dt.year == year].to_csv(year + '_snowfall.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: With python, we can even compress this 7 lines code to 2 lines.. (as far as I can go..)